# What is the criteria used for determining duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

The question in question: [How can I exec a function where the name comes from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203045/how-can-i-exec-a-function-where-the-name-comes-from-a-string)

The linked duplicate: [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

The text of the title is similar, and that is where the similarities end. The body of the newer one gives detailed code and is of a completely different solution than the one of which it was marked duplicate. The new question even refers to the potential duplicate, showing how the solutions don't work.

The 2 questions are about 15% similar. The title text is similar, while the body, scope, and solutions are completely different.

So I'd like to know: What is the criteria for determining duplicate? Is there such a thing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you include a solution in your question? That should go to the answers section...

Comment: See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) - yes, there is a criterion (not very explicit in the help center), but well-defined in various guideline posts: if an answer from another question B can be applied to question A, then A is a duplicate. Age does not matter: only the answer quality does (if a newer Q&A has *better* answers -> it should be used as the target)

Comment: The criteria is broadly something like "one can find the answer to A in the answers to B".

Comment: Your question has 3 problems in 1. It's not only a dupe, but too broad as well

Comment: @yivi - switched the A/B order to match your comment :)

Comment: I'm not an expert on React, but doesn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30602469/479156) answer your question? For vanilla JS [it works perfect](https://jsfiddle.net/kujn25qg/).

Comment: Have you read all 34 answers on the duplicate and concluded that all of them didn't work?

Comment: Would it not be obvious? "How to make pancake" is a duplicate of " how pancakes are made?" let's not look at the heading, if the content is similar in asking the same thing, resulting in the same answers to be given, it is a duplicate. Keep in mind that the questions are closed by humans, some people (even with the given reputation) does not consider reading everything, they see a heading/content and mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @Gerhard - it makes me wonder if by chance the current wording is not to blame. We close due to answers, yet the closure happens against the *question*. It is obvious to *us* that this is not about the other question, but a lot of the times (if not most) the OP complains "but the question is asking about X, and mine is about Y" (disregarding the fact that there is a connection of the form X -> Y)

Comment: @OlegValter This is the point here: the titles are worded similarly, but everything else about the question is different. The people that voted to close clearly read the title without understanding the question or the problem. Not by chance, either. I'm betting that it ties directly to the high downvote count yet low response count on this meta question... drive-by downvoting from reading just the title, as if it was Reddit.

Comment: @OlegValter I think that given these situations that people should consider the closure conditions. I for one will not link a duplicate if the linked answer does not answer the current question, but that said I will not link a duplicate if the answer to a duplicate question has not been accepted. This to me means that if the question is the same and the answer was not accepted, even though the questions are exactly the same, the questions (old or new) were never answered and therefore should not be closed.

Comment: @Gerhard - you overestimate the meaning of acceptance, I wouldn't go for it - judge the answers by their merit, it has nothing to do with the OP accepting them or not. I actually wouldn't go for any criteria other than my judgment whether the answers in the target Q&A provide a solution. This really should be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @OlegValter no, I fully agree. by acceptance I mean OP has speculated in comments that he/she cannot find the provided solution as relevant, not in the sense of people not understanding how the system works. a Solution should be tried and tested. I am considering posting an answer to the posed question, maybe i can make clear what I am trying to say. :)

Comment: @Gerhard - sorry, it is hard to assume you mean confirming that the solution is not working when we have a feature of "accepting" answers, so the usual meaning is "check for the big green checkmark" :) I have no issues with the approach then, obviously

Comment: @monsto - I wasn't talking about your case, more in general, thinking aloud, so to speak. Regarding your comment, though: if I were you, I would really avoid accusations like "drive-by downvoting", it really doesn't go well with the community. Better keep things from flaring up. Besides, this is quite a basic topic for JS SMEs and I can attest to that - so downvotes likely come from the fact + the notorious Meta Effect.

Comment: @OlegValter, oh no, I agree, not at all. Let's consider _"my pc screen is black"_ with answers _"did you switch it on?"_ The ratio of accepted answers would be low based on the basic understanding of technology, but we both would know which answer would be accepted and solve the issue and closing as duplicate would be off no hassle here. Compare that to _"what is the meaning of life?"_. No answer to this can be accepted as they will all be opinion based, yet the question can exist many times and therefore can also be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @monsto - also what might've contributed is that you declare `doOther ` with `const` but then proceed to dismiss solutions because the function is not found on the global object (`window` in your case) whereas it is also a basic topic that `const` declarations do not create global bindings (i.e. you can't do `window[<function name here>]`) unless you declare it with `var`, `function` or forget the keyword completely. P.s. Before this turns sour, don't consider this as an attack, it is rather an attempt to provide some thoughts on why the post is badly received.

Comment: @OlegValter [why don't const and let statements get defined on the window object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55030498) for (yet another) dupe to mention here that addresses the behaviour.

Comment: @Gerhard - well, I just read your first comment, in particular, the "if the answer to a duplicate question has not been accepted" part as looking for an accepted answer (in a literal sense). No problem with the stance you take on the matter otherwise. Frankly speaking, I don't like closing something as a duplicate to anything but a superb answer set (although sometimes the opposite is unavoidable).

Comment: @VLAZ - yup. Actually, upon reading through the question thoroughly, I don't see why the target Q&A does not answer the question the OP has. Granted, one has to get a grasp on language basics to apply, but I always considered that a prerequisite.

Comment: "if an answer from another question B can be applied to question A, then A is a duplicate" - this is very clearly an idiotic criteria. Are "what tool do you use to screw in screws?" and "how do you open a paint can?" duplicate questions? Only a Stackoverflow mod would say yes.

Answer (score 5):

At this point the burden shifts from, "Why are these questions considered similar" to, "How can I prove that these questions are dissimilar?"

At its core, you're asking the same question:  how do I get JavaScript to execute function names that are strings instead of actual function calls?

Your first step to proving their dissimilarity would be to first convince enough of us that you're *not* looking for a way to execute function calls described as strings.

Comment: "*how do I get JavaScript to execute function names that are strings instead of actual function calls?*" that's not quite what the closed question was asking. At least, not in the exact same way as the duplicate target. The dupe is more similar to [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463) but not quite, since *in addition* to having to fetch something by a path, it also has to execute it *and* provide arguments. Where as the closed question is just asking how to get a function by its name as a string and execute it. No path, no args.

Comment: With that said, some of the answers in the dupe are applicable. And [“Variable” variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530) can provide the other half of the intent - finding one thing by its string name. With that knowledge [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359788) can be stripped down for the parts that are just relevant to execution.

Comment: That doesn't answer the original question: "What is the criteria for determining duplicate?" I want to know what the true criteria is, whether it's loose or specific, so that I can avoid it in the future. It seems tho, based on the comments and responses, that the primary lesson is to avoid even remotely similar titles, as the titles will be read without the question body or solutions considered.

Comment: @monsto:  I would respectfully disagree.  There are a lot of factors at play as to why a question is closed as a dupe at all, notably starting with subject-matter experts in that tag who believe this to be something similar to what they've seen before.  If they believe then that it's a dupe, then we're implicitly trusting them with that decision, while the rest of us don't quite have that context into what is being asked.

Comment: @monsto:  So instead of worrying about what *could* qualify as a dupe, focus more on the human element of dupe closure and indicate that, somehow, your question isn't the same as the one that's being asked, or that the answers in the other question don't apply to your situation.  Be explicit and provide comprehensive examples (e.g. "This question isn't asking the same thing as the duplicate because [insert very explicit rationale here], and I'm looking for answers specifically in the area of [insert very narrow answer domain here].").

Comment: @monsto:  The brutal fact of Stack Exchange is that once a question is closed, the burden is really more on the OP than the community to prove why the closure was in error and why it should be reopened.  We deal with false positives all the time on Meta, but thus far you haven't really indicated *why* this is a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - the linked question is actually a bit different to yours. It *does* have some answers than can help you but at its core, it seems to ask for a different thing.

Your question is actually a lot closer to ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript) <sup>*</sup> - you want to treat a string as a variable - in your case a function. I have added it to the duplicates list because it's a prerequisite to understanding the solutions in [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) - at its core you *cannot* have "variable variables" but you *can* lookup a variable in an object. You can then add `()` at the end to execute it, if it is a function.

---

<sup>*</sup> that's a term [coming from PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).